# router in bridge mode and CPU with 2 NIC

Tags: linux, networking, router, routing

I have a computer 2 NIC (Windows and Gentoo Linux)  and the CPU should handle the routing instead the business capble router I have received from my provider.

I want to get rid of the NAT routing capabilities of my business NAT Router and this router is capable to be set in bridge mode.

If I set the router in **BRIDGE Mode**, what will happen ?

Will the CPU receive on the connected NIC the WAN address of the router and I have the capabilitie to setup my own network with ip forwarding ?

I am looking forward to hear from you.

Thanks, Tamer

Answer (score 2):

> Will the CPU receive on the connected NIC the WAN address of the router and I have the capabilitie to setup my own network with ip forwarding ?

Yes. *The whole point* of a 'bridge' mode is that the ISP device only acts as a modem or media converter, not as a router. Your computer will get a direct MAC-layer connection to the ISP and should be able to obtain a WAN address using DHCP (or PPPoE, depending on the ISP).

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot.  
I have searched the whole internet for these 2 lines. :-)